# Commands not work after install using npm in MacOS

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, terminal, zsh

sup guys! I'm trying to run some commands after install using "npm install ", but nothing work...

examples:
`npm install -g yarn`
or
`sudo npm install -g yarn`

`changed 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 2s
found 0 vulnerabilities`

now I try run `yarn --version`
terminal return: **zsh: command not found: yarn**

my ~/.zshrc:

```
source /Users/mac/.bash_profile
source $HOME/.bashrc
source $HOME/.bash_profile
export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH
```

my ~/.profile

```
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
source ~/.profile
```

Running `npm prefix -g` terminal return `/Users/mac/.npm-global` I create that folder and set prefix with commands:

- `npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`
- `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`
- `source ~/.profile`

If run `npm prefix`  terminal back `/Users/mac`

If I try:

- `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node`
  or
- `sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/node /usr/lib/node`
  or
- `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm`

Terminal return: `Error “Operation Not Permitted”`
so I Disable System Integrity Protection (rootless) in Mac and trying again, this time terminal return: `ln: /usr/bin/node: Read-only file system`

Now it's been 2 days trying to solve this, I really don't know what to do now...